# How to convert CAML to plain text with a script?

Tags: xml, caml

I downloaded files from an online database. All the files contain one or two paragraph in CAML format which is really inconvenient for my use.

As an example:

```
"<caml:Content xmlns:caml=\"http://lc.ca.gov/legalservices/schemas/caml.1#\"><p>(a)<span class=\"EnSpace\"/>Every home solicitation contract or offer for home improvement goods or services which provides for a lien on real property is subject to the provisions of Chapter 1 (commencing with Section 1801) of Title 2 of Part 4 of Division 3.</p><p>(b)<span class=\"EnSpace\"/>For purposes of this section, “home improvement goods or services” means goods and services, as defined in Section 1689.5, which are bought in connection with the improvement of real property. Such home improvement goods and services include, but are not limited to, burglar alarms, carpeting, texture coating, fencing, air conditioning or heating\nequipment, and termite extermination. Home improvement goods include goods which, at the time of sale or subsequently, are to be so affixed to real property as to become a part of real property whether or not severable therefrom.</p></caml:Content>"
```

(this is stored in a .lob file --- I have thousands of files like that)

I have a shell script to push this data (stored in thousands of files) in my local database. I intend to use this data in my app but I only need the text part - without all the CAML tags.

I'm looking for a script or tool to convert all CAML paragraph to plain text in all the files. I will then re-populate my MySQL local database. Anyone knows what the best way to do it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

After some fits and starts, the way I went around it was using a python script. More specifically, I used the beautifulsoup library.

Like so:

```
import bs4 as bs


source = """"<caml:Content xmlns:caml=\"http://lc.ca.gov/legalservices/schemas/caml.1#\"><p>(a)<span class=\"EnSpace\"/>Every home solicitation contract or offer for home improvement goods or services which provides for a lien on real property is subject to the provisions of Chapter 1 (commencing with Section 1801) of Title 2 of Part 4 of Division 3.</p><p>(b)<span class=\"EnSpace\"/>For purposes of this section, “home improvement goods or services” means goods and services, as defined in Section 1689.5, which are bought in connection with the improvement of real property. Such home improvement goods and services include, but are not limited to, burglar alarms, carpeting, texture coating, fencing, air conditioning or heating\nequipment, and termite extermination. Home improvement goods include goods which, at the time of sale or subsequently, are to be so affixed to real property as to become a part of real property whether or not severable therefrom.</p></caml:Content>"""

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")


print(soup.get_text())
```

Output:

```
"(a)Every home solicitation contract or offer for home improvement goods or services which provides for a lien on real property is subject to the provisions of Chapter 1 (commencing with Section 1801) of Title 2 of Part 4 of Division 3.(b)For purposes of this section, “home improvement goods or services” means goods and services, as defined in Section 1689.5, which are bought in connection with the improvement of real property. Such home improvement goods and services include, but are not limited to, burglar alarms, carpeting, texture coating, fencing, air conditioning or heating
equipment, and termite extermination. Home improvement goods include goods which, at the time of sale or subsequently, are to be so affixed to real property as to become a part of real property whether or not severable therefrom.
```